# HostListener on React

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, event-listener

just starting with react. I have a question about @HostListener from angular. Can I use that in React? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

I tried to check my method, please look at the following snippet:

> @HostListener('document:fieldInput', ['$event']);
> fieldInput() {
> console.log(fieldInput);   }

Further I get this error message. Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.ts(1219)

I am coding in .js instead of .ts

Comment: This is an angular thing. You should just add events to the document in react

Comment: Is that addEventListener that you are recommending?